# Why I cannot use method setState() to array elements

Tags: reactjs

How to change `expanded` state of every object in array `list`. I want to change states inside `eachClose()` function. Every time when I trying change state of objects in array `list` i got that error from React compiler:

**TypeError: item.setState is not a function**

```
class Item extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                expanded: false,
            };
}

class ItemList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            list: [ 
                <Item />,
                <Item />,
                <Item />,
                <Item />,
                <Item />,
            ]
        };
    }
    

    eachClose = () => {
        this.state.list.map ((item, i) => item.setState({expanded: false}))
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="users">
                {this.state.list.map ((item, i) => <Item id={i} key={i} />)}
                <button onClick={this.eachClose}>Click</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `item` isn't actually an instance of `Item`, it's a React element, which is just a *descriptor* of what needs to be rendered. State is something that is internal to a component and not changed "from the outside". It looks like you might want to pass `expanded` as a prop instead.

Comment: Also storing React elements in state is unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said above, in your case `item` is not an instance of actual element. Moreover, keeping elements in state is an antipattern.

What you need to to instead - is to keep information about each element in the `list` state and render items with the information from the list. Like this:

```
class Item extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                expanded: props.expanded, // idea is to get expanded state from props
            };
     //.... rest of component. btw, probably you do not need state here at all
}    

class ItemList extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
    
            this.state = { // keep data for items, not items themself
                list: [ 
                    { expanded: true },
                    { expanded: true },
                    { expanded: true },
                    { expanded: true },
                    { expanded: true }
                ]
            };
        }
        
    
        eachClose = () => {
            const newList = this.state.list.map((item) => {
              return { ...item, expanded: false };
            });
            this.setState({ list: newList });
        }
    
        render(){
            // now render list according to info in state
            return(
                <div className="users">
                    {this.state.list.map((item, i) => <Item id={i} key={i} expanded={item.expanded} />)}
                    <button onClick={() => this.eachClose()}>Click</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is a codepen for you:
https://codepen.io/tamango/pen/LYbbqZa

Comment: fwiw, `item` is an object and this way you are mutating it at your `map`. it would be better if you do someting like `return { ...item, expanded: false }` or since it's only one key for this item `return { expanded: false }`

Comment: After click on the button props does not changing and the button doesn't update either.

Comment: @АлексейТовщик, yeah, that is because of wrong context (`this`) is binded in `onClick`. I've updated the answer with proper: `onClick={() => this.eachClose()}`

Please, try it. In short words, without arrow function wrapper, `this` in `eachClose` function will be binded to buttons `this` and not to the our component context. Using arrow function as a wrapper we bind this to the proper context, we may achieve same behavior using `onClick={this.eachClose.bind(this)}` but using arrow function is shorter and more readable.

Comment: The `list` with expanded values ​​is updated correctly, but its values ​​are not passed to props. Props is always `true` for `item`.

Comment: @АлексейТовщик, looks like you added some wrong changes. Here is a codepen, please take a look. `eachClose` button works correctly. https://codepen.io/tamango/pen/LYbbqZa